# Creating dynamic table rows

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I would like to know how to make this faster. It's okay for 100 rows but 1k, 10k, 100k is different.

```js
let array = {
  "PageOption": {
    "rowperpage": "10",
    "rowtotal": "235",
    "currentPage": "1",
    "divheight": "250"
  },
  "header": [
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "rownum",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "subpkid",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "destsubpkid",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "jrlpkid",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "max"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "jrltype",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "invtype",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "accountid",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "expID",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "invdate",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "invno",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "invdesc",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "dtamt",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "currate",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "dtamtf",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "isdebit",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "label": "cusid",
      "fontweight": "normal",
      "footer": "Sum"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "20000",
      "jrltype": "MOD",
      "jrlpkid": "526",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003632",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20120608101100001"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "1003764",
      "jrltype": "OD",
      "jrlpkid": "895",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003633",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100273"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "0",
      "jrltype": "KOD",
      "jrlpkid": "453",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003634",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101202101100001"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "124000",
      "jrltype": "DON",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003635",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20130124101100002"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "319090.59",
      "jrltype": "HOD",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003636",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100050"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "0",
      "jrltype": "YOSH",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003637",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100270"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "0",
      "jrltype": "ZOD",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003638",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100265"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "1",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "0",
      "jrltype": "GOD",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003639",
      "isdebit": "1232131231231",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100263"
    },
    {
      "rownum": "2",
      "currate": "2",
      "invtype": "3",
      "invdesc": "BEGIN GOOD",
      "invdate": "1900/01/01",
      "destsubpkid": "0",
      "dtamt": "INS",
      "cusid": "2014/03/22 13:35:02",
      "dtamtf": "0",
      "jrltype": "GOD",
      "jrlpkid": "1562",
      "subpkid": "190001011011003640",
      "isdebit": "123213",
      "expid": "1900/01/01",
      "invno": "0",
      "accountid": "20101023101100051"
    }
  ]
};
let counter=0;
let cont = $('.cont');
 function header(array){
        let div = $("<div></div>");
        let extraheader = $('<div></div>').addClass('extraFixedHeader');
        $(cont).find('table').parent().before(div.clone().addClass('fixedheaderHolder'))
        $.each(array.header,function(key,value){
        let main = $(cont).find('table').find('thead').children('tr');
        let mainfooter = $(cont).find('table').find('tfoot').children('tr');
        
        var html = $("<th></th>");
        let styleClass=' ';
        let checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" />').on('click',function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
        let span = $('<span></span>')
        let sorttrigger = $('<i></i>').addClass('fas fa-sort').addClass('sortTrigger text-secondary').attr('data-sorted','none');
        let icon = sorttrigger.clone();
        let label = $('<label></label>');
        let itemShow = label.clone();
        itemShow.off('click');
        itemShow.on('click',function(){          
          if(!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
          }
          let direction=$(this).find('span').attr('data-freeze-column');
          let colindex=$(this).parents('th').attr('data-column-index');
          let table = main.parents('table');

          let width = $(this).parents('table').find('tbody tr td[data-column-index="'+colindex+'"]').outerWidth()+6;
          let height = $(this).parents('table').find('tbody tr td').outerHeight();

          let headerheight = $(this).parents('th').outerHeight();
          
          switch(direction){
            case 'left':            
               table.find('tbody tr[data-row="true"]').each(function(){
                  $(this).find('td').eq(colindex).removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft').addClass('freezeLeft').css({
                    'width':width,
                    'height':height
                  });
               });
             
              $(this).parents('th').removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft').addClass('freezeLeft').css({
                'width':width,
              });

              break;
            case 'right':
              
              table.find('tbody tr[data-row="true"]').each(function(){
                console.log($(this).find('td').eq(colindex).outerHeight());
                  $(this).find('td').eq(colindex).removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft').addClass('freezeRight').css({
                'width':width,
                  });
               });
              $(this).parents('th').removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft').addClass('freezeRight');
              
              break;
            default:
             table.find('tbody tr[data-row="true"]').find('td:nth-child('+(+colindex+1)+')').removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft');
              $(this).parents('th').removeClass('freezeRight freezeLeft');
              break;
          }

        })

        icon.click(function(){
          let sortdir = $(this).attr('data-sorted');
          var table = $(this).parents('table');
          var col = $(this).parents('th').attr('data-column-index');
          icon.closest('tr').find('.sortTrigger').attr('data-sorted','none');
          icon.closest('tr').find('.sortTrigger').addClass('fa-sort').removeClass('fa-sort-up fa-sort-down');         
          var rows = table.find('tbody tr[data-row="true"]').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).parents('th').index()))

          switch (sortdir){
            case 'none':
              $(this).attr('data-sorted','asc');
              $(this).removeClass('fa-sort').addClass('fa-sort-up');         
               this.asc = true;
              
              break;
            case 'asc':
              $(this).attr('data-sorted','desc');
              $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-up').addClass('fa-sort-down');

               this.asc = false;
              
              break;
             
            case 'desc':
             $(this).attr('data-sorted','none');
             this.asc = 'none';
              $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-down').addClass('fa-sort');
              break;
          }
          if($(cont).find('.rowOrder ').children().length > 0){
              return false;
          }
        
          if (!this.asc){
            rows = rows.reverse()
          }
          if(this.asc != 'none'){
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            table.append(rows[i])
          }  
          }
          
        });
        let resizeable = div.clone().append(icon,span.clone().addClass('headerName').html(value.label)).addClass('resizeHeader');

        let dropdowntrigger = $('<i></i>').addClass('fas fa-bars headerdroptriger').attr({
          "data-toggle":"dropdown",
          "aria-haspopup":"true",
        });

        let dropdown = div.clone().addClass('dropdown-menu').css({
          'width':'100px',
        })
        let item = $('<a></a>').addClass('dropdown-item');
        // dropdown.append(item.clone().append(itemShow.clone(true).append(checkbox.clone(true),span.clone().text('To right').attr('data-freeze-column','right'))));
        // dropdown.append(item.clone().append(itemShow.clone(true).append(checkbox.clone(true),span.clone().text('To left').attr('data-freeze-column','left'))));
        // dropdown.append(item.clone().append(itemShow.clone(true).append(checkbox.clone(true),span.clone().text('None').attr('data-freeze-column','none'))));
        html.append(resizeable,div.clone().html('&nbsp;').addClass('resizeHandler')).attr('data-column-index',counter).attr({
          'data-height':html.outerHeight(),
          'data-width':html.outerWidth()
        }).hide();
        extraheader.append(div.clone().append(resizeable.clone(true).attr('data-column-index',counter)).addClass('fixedItem').css({
         
        })).attr('data-column-index',counter);
        switch(value.visible){
            case true:
                styleClass+='table-th-show ';
                break;
            case false:                
                styleClass+='table-th-hide ';
                break;
        }
        switch(value.fontweight.toLowerCase()){
            case 'lighter':
                styleClass+='table-font-weight-light ';
                break;
            case 'normal':                
                styleClass+='table-font-weight-normal ';
                break;
            case 'heavy':                
                styleClass+='table-font-weight-heavy ';
                break;
            case 'bold':                
                styleClass+='table-font-weight-bold ';
                break;                
        }
        switch(value.footer.toLowerCase()){
            case 'sum':
                styleClass+='table-footer-data-sum ';
                break;
            case 'avg':                
                styleClass+='table-footer-data-avg ';
                break;
            case 'min':                
                styleClass+='table-footer-data-min ';
                break;
            case 'max':                
                styleClass+='table-footer-data-max ';
                break;                
            default:
              styleClass+=''
              break;
        }

        html.addClass(styleClass);      

        main.append(html);
        
        mainfooter.append(html.clone().text(''));

        counter++;

    });
      $(cont).find('.fixedheaderHolder').append(div.clone().addClass('fixedrow').append(extraheader.children()));
    };
    header(array);
function body(array){
         let i=0;
        $.each(array.rows, function(key,value){
            let main = $(cont).find('table').find('tbody');
            let row=$('<tr></tr>').attr({
              'data-row':'true',
              'role':'row',
            });
            let td='';
            if(i==0){
             row.addClass('RowSelected');
            }
            let k = 0;
            let currentrow=array.rows[i];
            let countercolindex = 0;
            $.each(currentrow,function(key,value){

                let headerProp=array.header[k].label.toLowerCase();            

                td=$("<td></td>").attr('data-column-index',countercolindex);

                td.text(currentrow[headerProp]);
                td.on('click',function(){
                  if(main.find('.RowSelected').length > 0){
                      main.find('.RowSelected').removeClass('RowSelected');
                      main.find($(this)).closest('tr').addClass('RowSelected');
                  }
                  else{
                      main.find($(this)).closest('tr').addClass('RowSelected');
                  }
                })

                row.append(td);
                countercolindex++;
                k++;

            });
    
            main.append(row);
            
            row='';
            i++;
        });
    }
     body(array);
     $('table tbody tr')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cont'>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: For a high number of rows, the performance cost will be high no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but 1k, 10k, 100k is different

If you take a step back from code and look at the bigger picture, nobody actually reads 100k table rows in one session. It would be 100 rows at best, then people start skimming. At that point, all the effort of rendering is for nothing.

One good example of this is Google. When you search for a term, it can return millions of matches. However, Google only renders *the first 10* and paginates the rest away. Another would be log aggregation platforms like [Scalyr](https://www.scalyr.com/) or [Sentry](https://sentry.io/about/). Logs can be hundreds of megabytes worth of log messages, but it only renders the first hundred or so. The rest you can reach via search filters, sorts and pagination.

So my advice would be to render only a limited subset at a time. At the same time move your focus towards implementing search capabilities. You might want to look into [Lunr](https://lunrjs.com/) for client-side search indexing capabilities.